# @Context is null during integration test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing, rest-assured

I am using spring boot 1.3.0 on a rest application. I'm trying to create an integration test using [RestAssured](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured). I am having a problem on the @Context. It doesn't get injected to the controller for me to get the URI.

Here's the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest("server.port=8080")
@ActiveProfiles(value = {"testing"})
public class InvoiceRestServiceIT {

    private static String INVOICE_DATA = "<invoice data>";
    private static String INVOICE_URL = "/customers/1q2w3e4r/invoices";

    @Test
    public void testPostInvoice() {
        given()
           .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
           .accept(ContentType.JSON)
           .body(INVOICE_DATA)
         .expect()
            .statusCode(200)
            .body(containsString("entity"), containsString("id"))
         .when()
            .post(INVOICE_URL);;
    }
}
```

Here's the service class(InvoiceRestService.java):

```
@Autowired
private InvoiceController invoiceController;

@POST
public EntityResponse add(InvoiceResource invoiceResource) {
    return new EntityResponse(invoiceController.createInvoice(invoiceResource));
}
```

Here's the controller(InvoiceController extending RestController):

```
protected Customer getCustomer() {
    Customer customer = customerRepository.findOne(getCustomerId());
...
}
```

Here is where the error occurs(RestController.java):

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;

protected String getCustomerStringId() {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(request.getRequestURI()); //<---- Here, request object is null
    if (!matcher.find()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find customer id in request URL");
    }

    return matcher.group(1);
}
```

Here's the error log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.store.rest.RestController.getCustomer(RestController.java:90)
at org.store.rest.invoice.InvoiceController.createInvoice(InvoiceController.java:87)
at org.store.rest.invoice.InvoiceController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2d6c1a2e.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
at com.store.rest.invoice.InvoiceController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$90cabdc3.createInvoice(<generated>)
at com.store.rest.invoice.InvoiceRestService.add(InvoiceRestService.java:72)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497
```

Did anyone encounter this? How to solve this issue?

Comment: Field injection causes all sorts of problems. Passing the request as a method parameter is simpler and more reliable.

Comment: I did that before posting this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that your *controllers* are more like utility classes and that your *service* is actually a controller. So in that regard, your `InvoiceController` is likely not a JAX RS root resource.

I think the simplest solution (if you want to continue along this route) is to delete the `@Context private HttpServletRequest request;` declaration in `RestController` and move it to `InvoiceRestService` like this:

```java
@POST
public EntityResponse add(InvoiceResource invoiceResource, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    return new EntityResponse(invoiceController.createInvoice(invoiceResource, request));
}
```

You'll then need to pass the `request` to your `InvoiceController` utility.

But... the most elegant solution is just to have JAX RS parse the ID from the incoming path. With `@Path` you can define placeholders for named segments of the path and have those segments injected into your JAX RS endpoint methods like this:

```java
@Path("/customers/{customerId}/invoices")
public class InvoiceRestService {

  @POST
  public EntityResponse add(@PathParam("customerId") String customerId, InvoiceResource invoiceResource) {
    return new EntityResponse(invoiceController.createInvoice(invoiceResource, customerId));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, we've tried all of the above and all works but the real reason we're using the context like this is that we capture the UserPrincipal from the request, which contains information that is audited. Rather than passing the audit information into every request, controllers just extend the RestController.

Comment: @Leo So maybe you want `@ModelAttribute` advice?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with REST Assured 2.2 you can use [RestAssuredMockMvc](http://rest-assured.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.2.0/apidocs/com/jayway/restassured/module/mockmvc/RestAssuredMockMvc.html) from the [spring-mock-mvc](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#Spring_Mock_Mvc_Module) module and avoid starting the web server to do the tests.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class, 
    loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
public class ApplicationTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(wac);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // your REST Assured test for any controller
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Autowired` annotation for request

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;
```

Comment: It got injected but introduced a new error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not a servlet request
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.currentRequestAttributes(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:311)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.access$400(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:64)
 at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils$RequestObjectFactory.getObject(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:325)